# Why using POST method in a form returns Error 404?

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra

I am completely newbie in ruby, so I made a form with POST http method, but it fails as follows:

```
ruby sinatra_msg.rb  
[2017-08-04 07:47:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-08-04 07:47:50] INFO  ruby 2.3.3 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v2.0.0) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2017-08-04 07:47:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18141 port=4567
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2017:07:48:00 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 458 0.0083
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2017:07:48:00 -03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 458
- -> /
```

I have the following file tree:

```
.
├── sinatra_msg.rb
└── views
    ├── index.erb
    └── msg.erb
```

Content of sinatra_msg.rb:
    # coding: utf-8
    require 'sinatra'

```
post '/' do
  body = params[:body]
  erb :index
end

post '/show-msg' do
   msg = params[:msg]
   text = params[:text]
  erb :msg
end
```

Content of index.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Testing Sinatra post</h2>

<form action="/show-msg" method="POST">
  subject: <input name="msg[subject]"> <br />
  text: <input name="msg[text]"> <br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This a content of msg.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Testing output</h2>
<h1>Hi!</h1>

<p>
<%= params['msg']['text'] %>
</p>

<a href='/'>Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with this code?
(Using ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-l])

### UPDATE:

I've replaced `POST` by `GET`only in the first section and it worked:

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  body = params[:body]
  erb :index
end

post '/show-msg' do
   msg = params[:msg]
   text = params[:text]
  erb :msg
end
```

I wonder if is that right, can I do only GET for '/' ?

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct.

When you access a page in your browser, the browser sends a GET http method by default, you have to specify the POST when you want.

It is possible to POST to '/', there is no constraint on HTTP on which method can be applied to an url.

Comment: So, why did that code result in error 404 when using `post /` ?

Comment: Because you the browser issue a `get /` not `post /` :) whatever you type in your browser's address bar become a `get` by default.